# Android String operations, separate lines in a string

Tags: java, android, string

I have a output in form of:

```
 {"status":"07\/09\/201207:16||heythisisatestquestion||AndyesIreallyansweredthisquestiontoo-||07\/09\/201207:10||heythisistestquestion||ThisismyresponsetoyourTESTquestion-yes,Ireallyansweredyou.:-)||07\/09\/201206:29||sos||SOSagain-yes||07\/09\/201206:27||sos||SOSagain-yes||07\/09\/201205:05||test||Yes,respondingtothisTEST-yes,it'sworking","phone":"xxxxxxxxx"}
```

What I want to do is, I should get each values separated by || in an **Array**

Eg :

```
 **07\/09\/201207:16 .. 07\/09\/201207:10 .. 07\/09\/201206:29**  should be in array date

 **heythisisatestquestion .. heythisistestquestion .. sos** should be in array question 

 **AndyesIreallyansweredthisquestiontoo .. ThisismyresponsetoyourTESTquestion .. Ireallyansweredyou**
```

should be in array Answers, how can i separate each values by matching keyword ||.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP to generate the JSON you can find a similar function in [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) 
using the expression and then send the array or in java

```
    int count=0;
        String[] arr;
        arr=str.split("\\|\\|");
        for(int i=0,j=1,k=2;i<str.length;i+=3,j+=3,k+=3)
    {

    array1[count]=arr[i];
    array2[count]=arr[j];
    .....
    .....
count++;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should parse the JSON to get the status string.

Then split the status string along `"\\|\\|"`. i.e. `.split("\\|\\|")`. And pick out the tokens in group of 3.

Assuming the format of the status text is always valid:

```
 ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

 for (int i = 0; i < tokenArray.length / 3; i++) {
     date.add(tokenArray[i * 3]);
     question.add(tokenArray[i * 3 + 1]);
     response.add(tokenArray[i * 3 + 2]);
 }
```

Comment: can you please give a working example , sorry i am new to java and android

Comment: Ok i used split and i am getting all values in an array, now how should pick tokens and add them in separate arrays. -Thnks for quick response